# Delayed::Job run_at not being honored in cucumber test

Tags: ruby, cucumber, delayed-job

I'm running an existing cucumber suite that exercises code that enqueues delayed jobs, none of which include any "run_at" conditions. However, I've now introduced a job that gets enqueued with "run_at" in the future, and it does exactly what I want. However, when I exercise my new feature, I find the job is being executed immediately.

I found this somewhat promising line in a setup file:

```
# Run all delayed jobs inline
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false
```

I hoped that changing the value to true would help, but that causes none of the jobs to be run.

So how do I get the run_at to be honored and still have other jobs run as soon as they're enqueued?

Answer (score 1):

So, this now makes sense. The "Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false" causes jobs to be executed inline. Setting it to true puts the jobs in the database . . . where they sit forever because I don't have anything in place to work them off!

Answer (score 0):

DelayedJob 4.1.0 [now supports](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/commit/ce88693429188a63793b16daaab67056a4e4e0bf) `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs` being a block.

You could do:

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = ->(job) {
  job.run_at && job.run_at > Time.now.utc
}
```